# Black screen and beeping.

Tags: shortcut-keys

I've tried booting everyway I know how. Ctrl,alt, delete will sometimes stall it out until I release them. The 3 utility button at top right of keyboard panel (Dell Inspirion) will flash one after the other like normal, but they won't stop and I never get anything other than the black screen and beeping. I fear it has something to do with a USB that was improperly removed. Or maybe when my phone was plugged in. I was somehow able to get it to reboot once, but after I shut it down and restarted it did the same thing out of nowhere. Been trying to find some waves using hot keys or button sequences. But a lot of the keys are not labeled with their alternate functions. Please help.

Comment: If you can't even get past POST (or to it it seems), you have a hardware or BIOS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Going to be hardware. Especially make sure memory is seated properly. I can't count how many times i've seen this.